# Google Places API results based on area outline instead of radius

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am creating a directory using the Google Places API to return listing results.

I am having a problem when searching a region as it defaults to radius based results and that doesnt catch the outer most corners of the region unless we have a huge radius specified in which case it catches a ton of results from neighbouring regions.

Is it possible to have specific searches return boundary based listing instead of radius.

For example, in Prague there are 22 regions within the greater city.

If I search for Prague 4 and use Google autocomplete to select the region "Prague 4" it gives me radius based results that include many results from its neighbour "Prague 2" as google drops its pin right on the border of Prague 4 & 2.

Any help is much appreciated as this is quite a puzzle.

For context here is an image of Prague 4's boundaries, Prague 2 sits right on top of it.

How can we produce results only within the red boundary line?

[Prague 4 region outline google maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaetD.jpg)

Comment: OR an easier alternative and possible more desirable might be if it was possible to detect specific search queries and redirect them to landing page(s) for each region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature request similar to your's was filed in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827732

As you can see Google set it to Won't Fix (Intended Behavior) status with the following reply:

> In fact, Places API will approximate your location and radius to a roughly rectangular region (as typically defined by bounds in the Geocoding API) that fits the circle defined by your location and radius.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks @xomena, appreciate the feedback.